# How does one set document class options (e.g. paper size) for LaTeX output?

Tags: r, knitr

The [`header`](http://yihui.name/knitr/options#package_options) option lets you insert TeX code in the preamble after `\documentclass{article}`, but what if I want to change the default paper size or the default font size?

For this, I would need to insert text between `\documentclass` and `{article}`, for instance: `\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}`.

Update: I forgot to mention that I am using `spin()` to generate the PDF document via LaTeX.

Comment: This is obviously a question about `r`, why migrated into tex?

Comment: @kohske Seconded - the question and its answers are immaterial to anyone interested in LaTeX outside of how it relates to R Markdown/YAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#' \documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
#' \begin{document}

mean(1:10)
plot(1:10)

#' \end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

There is support for specifying certain options in the YAML header; a [relevant page](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html) on the R Markdown website lists the following options:

- `lang`: Document language
- `fontsize`: Font size
- `documentclass`: Document class
- `classoption`: Options for `\documentclass`
- `geometry`: Options for `\geometry`
- `mainfont`, `sansfont`, `monofont`, `mathfont`: For Xe(La)TeX and Lua(La)TeX
- `linkcolor`, `urlcolor`, `citecolor`: Options for `\hyperref`

You may find it useful to check out the default LaTeX template used [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex).