# Make all fonts in beamer presentation larger

Tags: beamer, fontsize, knitr

I'm working in R and knitting my output into a beamer presentation (The script below can be copied into an R script). My titles are naturally larger than the main text. However, I would like everything to be larger, meaning that I don't want everything the same font size, but everything one font larger compared to what it is now:

```
#' ---
#' title: "title"
#' subtitle: "Subtitle"
#' author: |
#'   | Me
#' institute: University
#' date: January, 2018
#' header-includes:
#'   - \usepackage{array}         # #' fontsize: 13pt
#'   - \usepackage{multicol}
#'   - \usepackage{fontspec}
#'   - \setmainfont{Montserrat Bold}
#'   - \setsansfont{Roboto Light}
#' output: 
#'   beamer_presentation:
#'     toc: no
#'     slide_level: 2
#'     fig_caption: false
#'     latex_engine: xelatex
#' ---
#' ## Contents
#' 
#' \tableofcontents
#' 
#' # Introduction
#' 
#' ## More Text
#' 
#'  
#' ## Title
#' 
#' - Part I 
#' - Part II
#' - Part III
#'
```

Changing the font size as I have it now doesn't work. Any suggestions on what I need to change?

Comment: Can you try to add `\makeatletter\def\beamer@size{{size14.clo}}\makeatother` to your header?

Comment: Or you could choose a smaller paper size.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I wasn't able to knit that. I got the following error: Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble

Comment: can you try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187757/36296 with `\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}`?

Comment: or the `#' fontsize: 13pt` you already have, but with 14pt? (13pt is no valid option for beamer)

Comment: The first comment with \documentclass[14pt]{beamer} doesn't work and the second suggestion doesn't change anything. I have tried up to 17pt, but the output still looks the same.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `knitr`, but can't you simply put `\fontsize{13}{16}\selectfont` somewhere? (After `\begin{document}`, perhaps?)

Comment: Thank you Erik. I can indeed add \fontsize{13}{16} to the document, but again nothing happens to the output.

Comment: It's hard to say based on the code you've provided. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on.

Answer (score 1):

In order to load a fontsize of 14, you have to have the `extsize` package installed.

From beamer manual :

> `\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}`
>
> Makes all fonts somewhat bigger. Requires `extsize` to be installed.

Comment: You don't have to load the package, it only needs to be installed.

Comment: @samcarter. Thanks. Edited my post. And I was wondering how does beamer parses a usepackage before reading the first line.